# Select from multiple tables where one has distinct values

Tags: sql, database, select, distinct

I have a simple problem here using SQL views. I just can't seem to figure it out at the moment.

- I have 2 tables, TableA and TableB.
- I want to retrieve FieldA in TableA
  and FieldB in TableB.
- The two tables are linked using an
  INNER JOIN.
- I only want rows where TableA.FieldA
  are distinct.
- The returned values should be of the top 10 items from TableB.FieldB

Simply using SELECT DISTINCT seems to be using the combination of the two fields to determine distinction.

Any ideas?

Here is a mock of the SQL currently returning all rows :

```
SELECT dbo.TableA.FieldA, dbo.TableB.FieldB
FROM dbo.TableA INNER JOIN dbo.TableB ON dbo.TableA.ID = dbo.TableB.TableAID
```

An example of data returned from this standard query would be :

```
FieldA  FieldB
John    78
John    21
Claire  18
Sam     16
John    25
Claire  48
Paul    53
```

What I am looking to have returned from the query would be :

```
John    78
Paul    53
Claire  48
Sam     16
```

**EDITED to try and make things a bit clearer and include missing information.

Comment: Your goal is not fully defined, which may be part of the problem. If you only want distinct FieldA from TableA, what rules determine which FieldA from TableB you will use if multiple exist?

Comment: You may want to define your table data.  i.e. the first set of data, FieldA FieldB, is that from TableB?  And you want the top ten in TableB defined by what? Any order?

Answer (score 1):

If there are two different values for field A in table b based on the join, how would you know which one to use?

You could try this but it may not choose the b value you want

```
SELECT dbo.TableA.FieldA, max(dbo.TableB.FieldA)
FROM dbo.TableA INNER JOIN dbo.TableB ON dbo.TableA.SomeID = dbo.TableB.SomeID
GROUP BY dbo.TableA.FieldA
```

Comment: Do you need ORDER BY max(dbo.TableB.FieldA) DESC LIMIT 10 too?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619103/select-from-multiple-tables-where-one-has-distinct-values/619468#619468) I think what you are trying to do is this:

Sum FieldB in TableB and then join it with TableA.

```
SELECT   TableA.FieldA,
         tmp.SUMFieldB
FROM     TableA
         INNER JOIN
                  (SELECT  TableAID,
                           SUM(FieldB) AS SUMFieldB
                  FROM     TableB
                  GROUP BY FieldA
                  ORDER BY SUMFieldB DESC
                  ) AS tmp
         ON       TableA.ID = tmp.TableAID
ORDER BY tmp.SUMFieldB DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT TableA.FieldA,
       tmp.FieldB
FROM   TableA
       INNER JOIN
              (SELECT  TableAID,
                       FieldB
              FROM     TableB
              GROUP BY FieldA
              ORDER BY FieldB DESC
              ) AS tmp
       ON     TableA.ID = tmp.TableAID
ORDER BY tmp.FieldB DESC
```